# Common authentication for different roles

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

My system is built with Laravel and features two separate authentication mechanisms, one for 'store' and another for 'admin', accessible via http://mysystem/store and http://mysystem/admin respectively.

It utilizes two distinct tables ('stores' and 'admins') for each authentication process. 
I need to know if it's possible for a user who has logged in through the 'admin' authentication to access the 'store' section at https://mysystem/store without going through the store's authentication process.

Comment: this is usually not a recommended way of separating the roles, what if in the future there comes another user with a different role? what will you do?

The best way is to have one authentication, different authorization and by this you can allow different users to have one role or more than two roles.

Comment: See You have the problem for the admin to access the store section now if there were proper authorization rules, then this problem will not came, and will just have to assign another role and will good to go

Answer (score 0):

For this you can simply create different roles to use same users table instead of admin and store, that will be the correct way to manage, or else you have to define different guards in auth.php to manage such things.